# Visual Studio Team Services - Run Functional Tests build task aborting after attempting test run

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nunit-3.0, nunittestadapter

When I attempt to use the Run Functional Tests task after successfully executing the Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task, the test run is aborting after a period of time with no actionable error reported.

> 2017-09-18T18:30:56.0416875Z ##[section]Starting: Run Functional Tests
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0436877Z ==============================================================================
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0436877Z Task         : Run Functional Tests
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0436877Z Description  : Run Coded UI/Selenium/Functional tests on a set of machines (using Test Agent) 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0446878Z Version      : 1.0.53 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0446878Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0446878Z Help         : [More Information] 
> (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=624389) 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0446878Z ===========================================================================
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.0486882Z Preparing task execution handler.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:56.2957129Z Executing the powershell script:
>  C:\agent_work_tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent_d353d6a2-e361-4a8f-8d8c-123bebb71028\1.0.53\RunDistributedTests.ps1
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2319065Z DistributedTests: Environment WinRm Protocol HTTP.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2419075Z DistributedTests: Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2419075Z DistributedTests: SourceFilter: ***test*.dll TestCaseFilter:
>  
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2419075Z DistributedTests: Run title: TestRun_TEST - Agile-ASP.NET (PREVIEW)-CI_20170918.17
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2429076Z DistributedTests: is automated: True
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2429076Z DistributedTests: build location: E:\Websites\BuildTest\
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2429076Z DistributedTests: build id: 147
>   2017-09-18T18:30:58.2429076Z DistributedTests: test configuration mapping:
>  
>   2017-09-18T18:30:59.1269960Z DistributedTests: Test Run with Id 4463 Queued
>   2017-09-18T18:30:59.3450178Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:31:09.6130445Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:31:19.8980729Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:31:30.1380968Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:31:40.4581287Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:31:50.6271455Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:32:00.8831710Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:32:11.0691895Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:32:21.3022127Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:32:31.6102434Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:32:41.8402663Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:32:52.4743296Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:33:02.7353556Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:33:13.0463866Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:33:23.4314250Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:33:33.6404458Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:33:44.0194836Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:33:54.6215437Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:34:04.9425757Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:34:15.1385952Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:34:26.2367049Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:34:36.1997011Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:34:46.4097220Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:34:56.6257435Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:35:06.9417750Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:35:17.7388546Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:35:27.4378244Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:35:37.6538459Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:35:47.8708675Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:35:58.1668970Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:08.3655493Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:18.5925493Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:28.8865493Z DistributedTests: Test run '4463' is in 'Aborted' state.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:38.8945493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1035493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1045493Z Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1045493Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1055493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1065493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 4463
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1085493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occurred during test execution. Try again.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1095493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : NUnit VS Adapter 2.1.1.0 discovering test is finished
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1095493Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1105493Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 4463
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1195493Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1715493Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
>   2017-09-18T18:36:39.1715493Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Functional Tests

These are the logs from deploying the Test Agent, where I can also see no issues, but I am including them for reference:

> 2017-09-18T18:24:59.2450114Z ##[section]Starting: Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2470116Z 
> ==============================================================================
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2470116Z Task         : Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2470116Z Description  : Deploy and configure Test Agent to run tests on a set of machines
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2470116Z Version      : 2.1.20
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2470116Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2470116Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=838890)
>   2017-09-18T18:24:59.2480117Z 
> ==============================================================================
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7892658Z 
> ****************************************************************
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7892658Z                     Task Input Information
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7902659Z ----------------------------------------------------------------
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7932662Z winRmProtocal            = Http
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7932662Z testCertificate          = true
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7952664Z runAsProcess             = true
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7962665Z logonAutomatically       = true
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7962665Z disableScreenSaver       = true
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7972666Z isDataCollectionOnly     = false
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7982667Z testPlatform             = 15.0
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.7992668Z agentLocation            = \TestAgent\TestAgent.zip
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.8002669Z updateTestAgent          = false
>   2017-09-18T18:25:01.8072676Z
>  ****************************************************************
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4813350Z Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4813350Z Inputs provided are:
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4813350Z Use HTTP Port: True
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4813350Z Disable Screen saver: True
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4823351Z Login Automatically: True
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4823351Z Run as process: True
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4823351Z Agent location: \TestAgent\TestAgent.zip
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4823351Z Update test agent: False
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.4823351Z Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
>   2017-09-18T18:25:02.5973466Z Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' on machine  is being run
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z     Deployment started on target machine...
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z Query for Testplatfrom version: 15.0
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z Testing container: 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D}'
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8168685Z Exists.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z Getting Visual Studio setup instances.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z Found 1 instances.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8178686Z Description   : Supports running automated tests and load tests remotely
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8188687Z DisplayName   : Visual Studio Test Agent 2017
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8188687Z Id            : c7ded16e
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8188687Z InstallDate   : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8188687Z Name          : VisualStudio/15.3.4+26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8188687Z Path          : C:\TestAgent2017
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8188687Z Version       : 15.3.26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z VersionString : 15.3.26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z Test Agent already exists
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8198688Z Version: 15.3.26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z DTAAgentExecutionService is not present on the machine
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z DTAExecutionHost is not running
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8208689Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 2 : [RemoteDeployer]
> [18:Sep:17:15:25:5:1565; 7084, 4] Created public key for communication
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8218690Z RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 :
>  [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:5:1565; 7084, 4] Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployerc612dfc5-c424-4fda-ae9a-cd2f906bce94 is running...
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8228691Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:6:1861; 7084, 6] Input file found
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8228691Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:6:1861; 7084, 6] Reading input parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8238692Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer]
> [18:Sep:17:15:25:6:2017; 7084, 6] Finished reading input parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8238692Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:07.8238692Z Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' on machine completed.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:08.8289697Z Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine is being run
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7900658Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7900658Z \ was deleted successfully.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7900658Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7900658Z Copying recursively from C:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\2.1.20\TestExecution.zip to C:\TestAgent on machine succeeded.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7910659Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7910659Z \ was deleted successfully.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7910659Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7910659Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7910659Z Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine completed.
>   2017-09-18T18:25:09.7950663Z Task 'SetupTestMachineForUiTests' on machine is being run
>   2017-09-18T18:26:09.7980660Z Task 'SetupTestMachineForUiTests' on machine is taking time. Please Wait
>   2017-09-18T18:27:09.7860642Z Task 'SetupTestMachineForUiTests' on machine is taking time. Please Wait
>   2017-09-18T18:28:09.7890639Z Task 'SetupTestMachineForUiTests' on machine is taking time. Please Wait
>   2017-09-18T18:29:09.7920636Z Task 'SetupTestMachineForUiTests' on machine is taking time. Please Wait
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6180457Z     Deployment started on target machine...
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6200459Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6200459Z Test User
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6200459Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6210460Z Test UserDomain
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6230462Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6240463Z Executing command : powercfg.exe /Change monitor-timeout-ac 0 ; powercfg.exe /Change monitor-timeout-dc 0 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6260465Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6260465Z Error :  
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6270466Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6280467Z Output :  
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6280467Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6280467Z Updating machine reboot count to : 1
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6280467Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6290468Z Currently test user is not logged in. Rebooting machine.
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6290468Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6290468Z Enabling auto logon
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6290468Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6290468Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6310470Z     Deployment started on target machine...
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6310470Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6310470Z Test User
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6310470Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6310470Z Test UserDomain
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6320471Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6320471Z Executing command : powercfg.exe /Change monitor-timeout-ac 0 ; powercfg.exe /Change monitor-timeout-dc 0 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6320471Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6320471Z Error :  
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6330472Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6330472Z Output :  
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6330472Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6330472Z Configuration for UI testing is completed
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6330472Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6330472Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6340473Z 5:11:9740; 428, 4] Created public key for communication
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6340473Z RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:11:9896; 428, 4] Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployerd61e768d-1f6c-4de3-912b-ba961a2bb337 is running...
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6350474Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:13:0036; 428, 6] Input file found
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6360475Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:13:0036; 428, 6] Reading input parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6360475Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:25:13:0192; 428, 6] Finished reading input parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6370476Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6370476Z Task 'SetupTestMachineForUiTests' on machine  completed.
>   2017-09-18T18:29:59.6390478Z Task 'TestAgentConfiguration' on machine  is being run
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9905825Z     Deployment started on target machine...
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9905825Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9915826Z Test User 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9915826Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9915826Z Test UserDomain 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9915826Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9925827Z Testing container: 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D}'
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9925827Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9925827Z Exists.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9935828Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9935828Z Getting Visual Studio setup instances.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9935828Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9935828Z Found 1 instances.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9945829Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9945829Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9945829Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9945829Z Description   : Supports running automated tests and load tests remotely
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9955830Z DisplayName   : Visual Studio Test Agent 2017
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9955830Z Id            : c7ded16e
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9965831Z InstallDate   : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9965831Z Name          : VisualStudio/15.3.4+26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9975832Z Path          : C:\TestAgent2017
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9975832Z Version       : 15.3.26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9985833Z VersionString : 15.3.26730.15
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9985833Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9985833Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9985833Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9985833Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9985833Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9995834Z VS path C:\TestAgent2017\Common7\IDE; Test window path C:\TestAgent2017\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
>   2017-09-18T18:30:44.9995834Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0025837Z Path: 
> C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0025837Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0035838Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0035838Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0045839Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0045839Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0075842Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.TestExecution.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0085843Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0095844Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0105845Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0105845Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0115846Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0135848Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0135848Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0145849Z Loading module from path
>  'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0145849Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0155850Z Loading module from path 
> 'C:\TestAgent\PrivateAssemblies\MS.VS.TestService.Client.Utility.dll'.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0165851Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0165851Z 
> ****************************************************************
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0165851Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0165851Z                     Configure Test Agent
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0165851Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0175852Z ----------------------------------------------------------------
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0175852Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0175852Z SetupPath                       : (C:\TestAgent)
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0175852Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0175852Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z AsServiceOrProcess              : (Process)
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z EnvironmentUrl                  : (dta://env/39a888b4-a200-42b4-8866-eaedb1da410a/_apis//201709181525023083)
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z 
>   
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z Capabilities                    : ()
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0185853Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z TestAgentVersion                : (15.0)
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z 
> ****************************************************************
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z Register the Agent with Id: 14
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z Starting scheduled task on Windows 7.
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0195854Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0205855Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 2 : [RemoteDeployer]
> [18:Sep:17:15:30:3:6202; 3168, 4] Created public key for communication
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0205855Z RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:30:3:6202; 3168, 4] Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployerc5e37723-02f4-42db-93b4-2eead65fe9cd is running...
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0205855Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:30:4:6489; 3168, 6] Input file found
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0215856Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:30:4:6489; 3168, 6] Reading input parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0215856Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer][18:Sep:17:15:30:4:6801; 3168, 6] Finished reading input parameters
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0215856Z 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0215856Z Task 'TestAgentConfiguration' on machine  completed. 
>   2017-09-18T18:30:45.0775912Z ##[section]Finishing: Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment

Notes: The tests I am attempting to run are NUnit tests, and I have installed the NUnit package and the NUnit 3 Test Adapter package to the project that is being built

Comment: Is there detail error message in Test Run (4463) and it's test result? Set System.Debug variable to true, then queue build and share the detail log on the OneDrive.

Comment: Due to restrictions within my orgranization, OneDrive is inaccessible. I have worked around this by creating a GitHub repository to house the detailed error log, found here: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Fredison/ErrorLog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround to this issue I have used the **Batch Script** task in VSTS to execute a batch script that executes **NUnit Console** ([available here](http://nunit.org/download/)). The batch script to achieve this simply looks like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" {Path to your project}\YourProjectName.csproj
```

In order to track the results of testing in VSTS, I simply added the **Publish Test Results** task and pointed it to the **TestResults.xml** file generated by NUnit Console.

Although different than the **Run Functional Tests** task that uses a test agent, this method fulfills all of my testing needs (with fewer headaches).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log, the reason is “**Test run directory 'E:\Websites\BuildTest\' does not contain any assemblies that match the specified criteria: 'NewTestingApp\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll**'

Based on windows machine copy file, there isn’t **NewTestingApp** folder, so log on to test machine and check the actual path of test assembly.

Comment: Although this seemed like a promising lead, the test still aborted and ultimately failed.